# split causing tail end to be lost

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am trying to keep the tail end of the split

```
myLink = link.split(/\d/, 2)[1]
```

However the string it is splitting

```
link = 1 some text 800 hello world
```

would get split like:

```
1,
some text
```

I end up losing the tail end `800 hello world`.

What can I do to keep this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing a limit of 2 to the split function so you are only getting two results in your split array. Omit the 2 and you'll get them all:

```
var splitArray = link.split(/\d/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use,

```
        myLink = link.split(/\d/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = '1 some text 800 hello world';

var myLink = link.match(/[A-Z\s]?[a-z\s]+|[0-9]+/g);

alert(myLink);
```

This will definitely lead you for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead in regexp

```
myLink = link.split(/(?=\d+)/, 2)[1]
```

Comment: this returns `1 some text, 8` in the array so the `[1] = 8 `

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = "1 some text 800 hello world";

var myLink = link.split(/\d+/,[0-9]);

alert(myLink[1]); //this will give you some text
alert(myLink[2]); //this will give you hello world
```

Comment: I want to keep the second set of numbers.